# turning my pi into a wireless access point, no I can't connect to pi and pi can't connect to the internet

Tags: access-point

I followed the instructions here https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point-routed.md

The pi isn't showing up on my phone when I look at things to connect to, and the pi itself can't connect to the internet, it says "no wireless interfaces found."

Does anyone have any idea of what I did wrong? or at the very least, how to reconnect it to the internet so I can try again.

thank you

Comment: which model pi is it?

Comment: @jsotola is that a static IP address

Comment: @JaromandaX it's a pi 3

Comment: @JacobWilson apologies ... yes, did you define a static IP address

Comment: @jsotola if that's the part where I added

interface wlan0
    static ip_address=192.168.4.1/24
    nohook wpa_supplicant

to dhcpcd.conf then yes I did it.

Answer (score 2):

The tutorial from the official Raspberry Pi web site is known to work but it uses traditional networking technology with additional helper programs (hostapd, dnsmasq, iptables) mixed up with modern **systemd-networkd**. For my opinion it is not very intuitive but error prone and does not illustrate the powerful networking issues of *systemd-networkd*.

I suggest to try a clean *systemd-networkd* solution as shown at [Setting up a Raspberry Pi as an access point - the easy way](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/88234/79866). For a routed solution you can use section **♦ Setting up an access point and with eth0, with NAT (recommended)**.